# Simple library to encapsulate a file in an uncompressed ZIP file?

Tags: c, linux, compression, zip

I want to send a file as an email attachment, but at present there is an email filter that prevents that. Is there a simple method or library to encapsulate a file of any length inside an uncompressed ZIP file? I'd like to avoid adding an actual ZIP library that compresses, if I can. For one thing, the file I'm sending is already compressed.

Comment: Change the extension to something the email system you're trying to thwart allows. Crafting a ZIP file header with zero compression and non-encrypted seems overkill, but doable by simple manufacturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip format has a stored method (method 0) that would allow you to simply enclose the file in the appropriate headers.  See the PKWare [appnote.txt](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) for a description of the format.  You would need to calculate the CRC-32 of the data to include in the headers.